# For Node.JS, where are the core modules in Win?

Tags: windows, node.js, configuration

From the [official api site](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) it says that core modules are installed at the /lib folder of the root folder of NodeJS, but when I was trying to search for it I didn't see the /lib folder.

Any idea?

Additionally, after I've done a

```
var a = require("a.js");
```

is it possible to get the corresponding path to a.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that means `/lib` folder is in source code not your computer. you can see it in [repository](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/lib).

and

there are two patterns for `require`

- absolute path: if the parameter is not started with `./' nor`'../', it's absolute path. so node look for it in core module(it's compiled in node runtime) or `node_modules' that you installed locally using npm.
- relative path: if the parameter is started with `./` or `../`, it's relative path. so node look for it relative path to current position.

it's so simple. and you can use `require.resolve('a.js')` to get absolute system path. but core modules don't has path since it's built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is good enough to resolve the question, it is worth mention that it has some misleading information regarding the patterns of required. From the very [Reference Documentation of Node](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_file_modules):

> A module prefixed with '/' is an absolute path to the file. For example, require('/home/marco/foo.js') will load the file at /home/marco/foo.js.
>
> A module prefixed with './' is relative to the file calling require(). That is, circle.js must be in the same directory as foo.js for require('./circle') to find it.
>
> Without a leading '/' or './' to indicate a file, the module is either a "core module" or is loaded from a node_modules folder.